# How to create new wordpress admin user from FTP

Tags: sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I haven't logged into the wordpress backend of my website in a couple years.

Now, however, none of the passwords I use seem to work. I request a reset, but I NEVER get the email.

I went into PHPMyadmin to change the password of the user, but that doesn't seem to work. The site is still not accepting the new password. I created a new user from phpMyAdmin and that user is still not recognized. So I'm not sure the database I'm updating is the correct database, however it's the only one available. Have I been hacked? I don't understand how none of my passwords are working, I am not receiving lost password emails nor are any of my new users or changed passwords from the phpMyAdmin being recognized.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: This literally has everything to do with programming: Wordpress, SQL, FTP. I am talking about Wordpress.org not .com. And resetting passwords from phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://wordpress.org/support/article/resetting-your-password/

1. Login to your site via FTP and download your active theme's functions.php file.
2. Edit the file and add this code to it, right at the beginning, after the first

   wp_set_password( 'password', 1 );

Put in your own new password for the main admin user. The "1" is the user ID number in the wp_users table.

3. Upload the modified file back to your site.
4. After you then are able to login, make sure to go back and remove that code. It will reset your password on every page load until you do.

Comment: oh, thank you, this worked. I still don't understand what happened: why none of the other routes worked. I'm wondering if I was hacked or if i need to do something else to the database. Thanks or your quick response. EDIT: Actually, now that I'm logged in, I don't recognize the username for the main admin account. Perhaps I was hacked.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you don't have access to database and don't have the user id, use the below code in your active theme's function.php:

[Refer here for more options: You can use  | ID | slug | email | login](http://[Refer%20her%20for%20more%20options:%20You%20can%20use%20%20%7C%20ID%20%7C%20slug%20%7C%20email%20%7C%20login%20][1]%20%20%20%20%20[1]:%20https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/)

```
$user = get_user_by( 'email', 'user@example.com' );
$id = $user->ID;
$password = 'your_new_password'; // Plain text password
wp_set_password( $password, $user_id );
```

Now the new password is: your_new_password.

Make sure to remove the code after your site is loaded once. You won't be able to login without removing this code as it will reset the password everytime page loads.